# Installing TLP power save stopped my wifi adapter from working

Tags: wireless, tlp

I am new to Ubuntu. I finally decided to dual boot (I need windows for ONE program: ArcGIS). Everything was going fine until I took my laptop to class and realized my battery power was draining like crazy (1.5 hours remaining at the start of a 3 hour lecture).

Due to this predicament, I decided to try out tlp. I followed a guide online on how to install tlp through the terminal and my Wifi stopped working.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hey! Quick update! I can indeed connect to my Wifi (the router/modem is about 25 feet away from me in the living room) only if the ac power is connected. However, there are two things that might be worth noting: 
1) The internet icon at the top right shows a monitor as opposed to the wifi signal icon.
2) My power just drained from 97% to 5% in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Please try turning off power management for the wireless: sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off. If it helps, we'll make it permanent.

Comment: Hah! I've been at it for hours yesterday and that's all it took.. Thank you so much, Chili555!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable wifi powersave in TLP permanently on battery you don't have to fiddle with iwconfig or rc.local (won't work reliable anyway).

Change the following line in [TLP's configuration](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html) instead:

```
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=N
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include all the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Only Ubuntu 17.04 has TLP 0.9.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10 and 16.04 has 0.8. I reckon "N" does not work on TLP version 0.8?

Comment: @JauntyDoe: Wrong. 0.8 works with Y/N. Was invented many years ago :-).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to permanently disable power management. The easiest is:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Right above exit 0, add a new line:

```
iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. If this is ineffective, for some reason, we'll try something else.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem,

I fixed my problem by

> Uninstalling TLP and Installing Wireless Drivers

Command: (to remove tlp) (sorry I have OCD)

```
sudo apt-get purge tlp
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Command: (to install 802.11 drivers) (I am on Kali rolling and using Wicd network manager)

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-brcm80211 firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer broadcom-sta-dkms
```

if you don't know the repository of Kali: ( Paste this in /etc/apt/souces.list and save )

```
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

I also noticed, while installing tlp, the package arping was replaced by iputils-arping. Hence,

```
sudo apt-get install arping
```

**Restart Required**

Thats it!

(if this works for you, please upvote so I can get right to answer, comment, upvote, etc)