# Is there a way of logging when wifi power management settings are changed?

Tags: ssh, network-manager, power-management

I have a Rock960 board running Ubuntu server. It suffers from a "bug" where SSH is extremely laggy because WiFi power management is turned on.

I've tried various solutions to permanently disable it:

- [Wifi power management turns back on when connecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649706/wifi-power-management-turns-back-on-when-connecting)
- [How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on)
- Adding a `powersave` option to my specific SSID configuration

None of them work (permanently). Something on the system is forcing power management on a few seconds after it's turned off, whether manually or through some config file. I've fixed this by running a bash script via `rc.local` which polls `iw` every few seconds and disables power management if it's turned on. This works, but it's frustrating not knowing what the actual problem is. Even running a cronjob every minute isn't enough.

The system is using NetworkManager as far as I can tell, but none of the configuration overrides seem to work.

Is there a way of figuring out what's enabling power management (perhaps via a log)?

The script, in case anyone finds it useful:

```
#!/bin/bash

management_off="Power Management: off"

while true; do
  status=`/sbin/iw wlan0 | grep "Power Management"`

  if  [ "$status" != "$management_off" ]; then
    /sbin/iw wlan0 set power_save off
  fi

  sleep 5

done
```

Comment: Are you using `tlp`? https://askubuntu.com/questions/545841/installing-tlp-power-save-stopped-my-wifi-adapter-from-working

Comment: It's installed, but `/etc/default/tlp` has `WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=off` and `WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=off`.

Comment: Some people have to use `cron` job to turn it off every minute: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, a minute isn't frequent enough. It renables within seconds.

Comment: My comment was to point out how other people have similar problems and what they did to solve them. I thought you might find their answers helpful.

Comment: No problem - I think most of the common suggestions are in the second link.

Answer (score 0):

Change in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf 
`wifi.powersave = 2` this should disable it with Network-Manger.source [git hub](https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55)

Without Network-Manger you can create an udev rule. `KERNEL=="wlan*", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off"`

For wlan* set the name of your interface.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, none of the recommended suggestions in those two links work e.g. altering `default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`. I've already done that and it has no effect.

I'll try your second suggestion though.